# WMI Queries takes long

Tags: powershell, wmi, wql, xenapp

I am querying around 280 XenApp servers. Here are my queries.

```
$bootupMemory = gwmi -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem" -ComputerName $srv
#$cpuLoad      = gwmi -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor" -ComputerName $srv
#$tSessions    = gwmi -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_TerminalService" -ComputerName $srv
$ima          = gwmi -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE name='imaservice'" -ComputerName $srv 
$mfcom        = gwmi -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE name='mfcom'" -ComputerName $srv
$ctxPrintMgr  = gwmi -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE name='cpsvc'" -ComputerName $srv
$msmqstatus   = gwmi -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE name='msmq'" -ComputerName $srv

$cDrive       = gwmi -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Logicaldisk WHERE deviceid='c:'" -ComputerName $srv
$dDrive       = gwmi -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Logicaldisk WHERE deviceid='d:'" -ComputerName $srv
$loginStatus  = gwmi -Query "SELECT loginsenabled, numberofsessions FROM Metaframe_Server" -Namespace root\citrix -ComputerName $srv
$load         = gwmi -Query "SELECT * FROM Metaframe_Server_loadlevel" -Namespace root\citrix -ComputerName $srv
```

Can you please suggest if this is optimal or can I optimize it.
Also how to incorporate a timeout parameter with each query. Is this possible?

Comment: WMI, there's only so much you can do before the real answer is a lot of multi-threading. I have an absurd system that spreads this kind of thing over several servers with going on for 100 threads each so I can pull data from a few thousand servers in a reasonable time frame. Had you looked at Start-Job and friends to begin with?

Comment: How does start-job help, I mean does it run simultaneously on all 280 servers. Also help me answer this: MY code is lying in a remote file share, Does start-job needs a local file on each server or can it handle a script on remote share.

Answer (score 5):

Running multiple queries for the same class against the same host is certainly not optimal. You can optimize your code to some extent by merging  the `WHERE` clauses of queries for the same class:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE name='imaservice' OR name='mfcom' OR name='cpsvc' OR name='msmq'
```

However, since you still need to query several different classes I would recommend running the whole code on the remote host and returning the result as a custom object:

```
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $srv -ScriptBlock {
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    bootupMemory = gwmi -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"
    #cpuLoad      = gwmi -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor"
    #tSessions    = gwmi -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_TerminalService"
    ima          = gwmi -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE name='imaservice'"
    mfcom        = gwmi -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE name='mfcom'"
    ctxPrintMgr  = gwmi -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE name='cpsvc'"
    msmqstatus   = gwmi -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE name='msmq'"
    cDrive       = gwmi -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Logicaldisk WHERE deviceid='c:'"
    dDrive       = gwmi -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Logicaldisk WHERE deviceid='d:'"
    loginStatus  = gwmi -Query "SELECT loginsenabled, numberofsessions FROM Metaframe_Server" -Namespace root\citrix
    load         = gwmi -Query "SELECT * FROM Metaframe_Server_loadlevel" -Namespace root\citrix
  }
}
```

Run `Invoke-Command` for each server in a separate [job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to run the queries in parallel and thus reduce overall processing time.

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $args[0] -ScriptBlock {
    New-Object ...
  }
} -ArgumentList $srv

Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

or (as Mathias suggested in the comments)

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $srv -AsJob -ScriptBlock {
  New-Object ...
}

Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Comment: Invoke-Command even has an `-AsJob` switch to make life easier!

Comment: I am trying to run invoke-command with -asjob, but I don't get any result back  
$serversRaw = qfarm /load
$hostnames =  for($i=3;$i -lt $serversRaw.length; $i++) { ($serversRaw[$i] -split " ")[0] }

if (($result = Read-host "Enter either c: or D: [default is C:]") -eq '') { $drive = "C:"} else {$drive = $result }



icm -computer $hostnames { gwmi -cl win32_logicaldisk | ? { $_.deviceid -eq $drive } | select size, freespace, pscomputername } -asjob


#$x | receive-job

receive-job